# WSO2 Identity Server Service Provider Role Mapping

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm evaluating WSO2 Identity Server 6.1. I'm configuring a Service Provider and trying to map the role Manager to service provider's GM role. Manager role is crated in the primary domaon. I get the below error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88quE.png)

Can anyone help?

I'm evaluating WSO2 Identity Server 6.1. I'm configuring a Service Provider and trying to map the role Manager to service provider's GM role. Manager role is crated in the primary domaon. I get the below error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IS-5.11.0 onwards Groups and Roles were treated as separet entities, which were treated as a single resource in prior versions. [https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/get-started/about-this-release/#new-features-and-enhancements:~:text=Separated%20%27user%20groups%27%20and%20%27roles%27%2C%20and%20introduced%20new%20role%20management%20APIs.%20For%20more%20information%2C%20see%20SCIM%202.0%20REST%20APIs](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/get-started/about-this-release/#new-features-and-enhancements:%7E:text=Separated%20%27user%20groups%27%20and%20%27roles%27%2C%20and%20introduced%20new%20role%20management%20APIs.%20For%20more%20information%2C%20see%20SCIM%202.0%20REST%20APIs).

Under Management console : `https://<host>:<port>/carbon` the differencition is not explicityly shown, but if you access the new Console application `https://<host>:<port>/console` you can see groups and roles separately.

From Managament console, if you create an entity under PRIMARY / any secondary usertsore domain it will be treated as a group.

Entities created under `Internal/` or `Application/` are treated as Roles.

For the role mapping you need to defined a role under `Internal/` domain

Comment: What needs to be set in the 'Local Role/Service Provider Role' line? Thank you